# Reverse exec bash

Tags: debian, shell

I'm using Debian and today I typed:

```
exec bash
```

in my terminal and somehow the `user@xxx` changed to `bash-4.4`.

How do I get back the `user@xxx`? I think it's better for me because for example it shows the path to my current folder etc...

Comment: Why are you even doing `exec bash` in the first place?

Comment: `exec bash` is a nice way to get a clean shell, reloading your `~/.bashrc` or whatever config file should be reloaded.

Comment: You can't reverse an `exec` operation -- it replaces your current process with a new one. The old process is dead and gone -- you might be able to replace your new process with something *more like* the old one, but you can't get the specific/actual/original instance back.

Comment: If this is a GUI, close the terminal emulator window and open a new one ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
exec bash -l
```

This will *replace* the current shell session with a `bash` shell started as a login shell.  A login shell will read your `.bash_profile` (or `.bash_login` or `.profile`, whichever it finds first) and other files where your prompt may be defined.

With `exec bash`, you replaced the current shell session with an interactive shell.  This will read `.bashrc` from your home directory.  If you don't set your prompt there, then you will get the default `bash` prompt.

Without the `exec`, you would have been able to just `exit` to get back to your old shell session.  With the `exec`, the old session is now gone.

You may also simply exit the shell and start a new one.

Comment: @KronwarsCZ It's very seldom that you will have to change the shell startup files in `/etc`. It is more common to modify the behaviour on a user by user basis in one's private shell startup files.

Answer (score 0):

The `user@xxx` is called the "prompt". It is set by the `PS1` environment variable. In bash, it defaults to `bash-<version>` which is utterly useless, but in principle a bash configuration file should always set it to something better.

A common case where you would get this is when you just created a `~/.bashrc` file that does not include `/etc/profile`. Without this file, bash was falling back to `/etc/profile` and you were getting your system's default configuration. With an empty or minimalist `~/.bashrc`, only your own configuration is loaded, and you don't get the benefit of what your distro or your sysadmin put in `/etc/profile`.

Solution: add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
    . /etc/profile
fi
```

Alternatively, set your prompt yourself by adding something like this (after the snippet above):

```
PS1="\u\h@\\$ "
```

(You can customize what appears in the prompt, make it colorful & all with tools like http://ezprompt.net/)

Comment: *shudder* I'm pretty sure you really don't want that in your .bashrc especially if /etc/profile yields output.